# Raptor Algorithm: Differences between trip and route

Tags: algorithms, routing

I'm reading [Microsoft's white paper "Round-Based Public Transit Routing"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/raptor_alenex.pdf) (the RAPTOR algorithm). In this algorithm, there are some definitions that I don't understand:

About trip:

> trip represents a sequence of stops a specific vehicle (train, bus,
>   subway, . . . ) visits along a line

About route:

> Each route consists of the trips that share the same sequence of
>   stops.

So, if I understand, trip means a "bus route" and a route is collection of trips to make a path? If my guess is true, why does it state:

> Typically there are more routes than trips

And if a route is just a collection of trips, how can I build all routes?

Answer (score 5):

**Trip** represents a **sequence of stops** plus **associated arrival and departure times** on each stop.

Group all trips by their sequence of stops, ignoring the time information, then each group of trips **sharing the same sequence** of stops forms a **route**.

eg. for air traveling, each flight is a trip, while each airline is a route, grouping all flights flying on the same airline.

What I saw in the paper is

> Typically, there are many more trips than routes.

Which is obvious since there is an one-to-many mapping between route and trips.

Comment: Woa. thanks so much. I'm reading this paper for many days. and It seems that rarely document I can search for this paper. I try so hard to understand trip and route but cannot. 
As you said, more trips than routes, and that's my typos :)
I search many places for sample implementation or more detail document about this algorithm but cannot. Can you propose for me a sample implementation or some document more detail in this algorithm than original paper. thanks :)

Comment: If you are interested in delving in a little more, I would defiantly familiarise yourself with [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/?hl=en). Once you understand how transit schedules are structured, a lot of the concepts described in the paper will make more sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, as the definition of **route** given in this paper does not seems to match the definition given in other standards (namely, GTFS). In GTFS a route is a somehow arbitrary collection of trips, but they do not have to share the exact same pattern of stop sequence (and they usually don't).

What the paper describes for a route is sometimes called a **route pattern** — a set of trips sharing an exact identical stop sequence.